# Disable 'record file and application usage' via command line

Tags: command-line

I am creating an install script. I would like to know how to disable the recent files appearing in the unity dash. I can disable them manually via

```
settings -> security & privacy -> files and applications -> record file and application usage
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do this with nearly any setting. In terminal type;

```
dconf watch /
```

Make a change in the settings GUI. When I toggled `record file and application usage` I saw the following output to terminal;

```
/org/gnome/desktop/privacy/remember-recent-files
false
```

Then use `gsettings` in terminal to change this setting

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-recent-files false
```

Comment: You might have to add the command to startup applications. They tend to not survive a restart sometimes.